# How to maintain a car's interior when left unused?

Tags: maintenance, car, skoda

My friend owns a five year old Skoda Fabia, which he uses once in a month or two as he goes out of the town frequently. His car is fully covered while it is parked in the garage.

Recently when he took his car out for a drive, there was no odor but he found a white powder like substance on the steering wheel. Could that be dust or something else ?

How could this happen when the car is fully covered? How to maintain the car's interior during these times?

Comment: If there was white dust, I'd suggest it was some kind of fungus growing inside. The only way to keep this from happening is to ensure it's clean before it gets put under the cover, or for it to get sent to a "boarding house" for cars (climate controlled storage). Those places keep the exterior and interiors in great shape while you're not using the vehicle.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to ensure the inside of the car does not get damp - even in a garage, condensation can cause mildew or mould to grow.

One way to keep it dry is to use a passive dehumifier - basically a material (commonly crystals) that absorbs moisture from the air, in the same way as the silica gel sachets you get in boxes of electrical appliances. For a cheap solution, you can even use cat litter for this...

Comment: I have an old sock filled with silicone based (that's important) cat litter sitting on the parcel shelf of my VW Bora at the moment and it's fiercely effective at soaking up moisture from inside the cabin.